# How can we add multiple ListView in Same Activity?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_stats"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/plain_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_statsheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dip"
        android:background="@drawable/headerbar_stats"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/statsheader" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtworktcompltd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/workt_completed"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="22dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewwoktcompleted"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalworktTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="@string/workttotal_time"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="22dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtexcompltd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="@string/ex_completed"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="22dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewexcompleted"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:minHeight="0dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalEx"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/extotal"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="22dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtweightloss"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/txtweightlossed"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="22dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to display two  listview in an activity,the contents in listview loading dynamically. I want to add more components below the second listview.When I am using scrollview can see only one row in each listview.Without using scroolview can see all the contents in listview..But cant see the components below the second listview..can anyone please help me to add multiple expandable listview in an activity??

Comment: I've done that quite a while ago. I think I wrapped the TextView/ListView in a LinearLayout each. The TextView would have fixed height, while the ListView had fill_parent or wrap_content. I then added the weights to the LinearLayouts, and wrapped those in another LinearLayout. This only worked for split-screen though, not expandable.

Comment: When I had to do two-part listview with expandable parts, I added a wrapper-object around my listview item, and rendered the items differently based on type through the Adapter. One of the identifiers with a SectionHeader, which would then take part of that TextView between the two listviews. Worked like a charm. No Scrollview needed.

Comment: This is popular [**issue**](http://goo.gl/hPCHi). You can search calculate listview height [**here**](http://goo.gl/wNhmj). Calculate your listview height depend on number of items.

Comment: didnt get any proper solution for the current issue,Here I am adding each item using custom adapter class.I want increase the height depend on item.Also I want show some components below the second listview.When loading second listview changed the size of first listview automatically..please aanybody know the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your ScrollView:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: when I added android:fillViewport="true" to Scrollview each listview just show 2 rows ..Its not working..